# Robot framework plugin does not show-up in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, robotframework

installed the latest version of Jenkins 2.271
https://www.jenkins.io/download/

then installed the Robot framework plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/robot/#releases
2.12

[image]

Then when adding a new step after build attempt it should show all the options of the plugin.

But it doesn't do that, what can be the cause, I am clueless now...

Comment: yeah of course, multiple times.

Comment: Add this fact to the question please.

Answer (score 0):

It's a poorly named plugin: should be **Robot Framework Publisher**. If you read the [Configuration section of the plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/robot/#documentation), you'll see:

> - Select: **Build -> Add build step -> execute shell/Execute Windows batch command**
> - Add the command to run the tests. You might have direct robot/jybot command here like `robot --variable name:value --outputdir my_robot_results my_test_suite` or in case you need to do something
>   more, you can call any script that you use for running the tests.
>   Relevant part from Robot Jenkins Plugin point of view is that this
>   script generates the Robot outputs.
> - Force your Robot script to return successfully from shell with `exit 0` to empower the plugin in deciding if the build is success/failure
>   (by default Robot exits with error code when there's any failed
>   tests). You can do this for example by adding `--nostatusrc` to your
>   test run (see Robot Framework user guide for details).
> - Select: **Post-build Actions -> Publish Robot Framework test results**

Thus you will only see a robot entry in the Post-build step to gather the results.

Note: [JENKINS-36954](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-36954) and OP's comments suggests you must also add [matrix-project](https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-project), which as of v.2.1.2 remains declared as "Optional" but appears to be required.

**Update** (2012-12-17): It would appear [JENKINS-36954](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-36954) is the culprit. I added steps to reproduce on the ticket, proposed sol'n,  which has been accepted and PR has been merged.  Expect to see it resolved in v.2.1.3.

Comment: Okay, but that is not the solution for showing the plugin options in the last step.

Comment: It is Dutch. (Hollanda, The Netherlands, "Amsterdam"). :) What I wonder is now... I'm using open source Java 11. Could that be a problem/reason? ( https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/11/ )

Comment: another step further: MESSAGE: No valid crumb was included in the request. when uploading .hpi file.

Comment: The crumb issue is you need to log back in, not just refresh page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason but after trying to use the E-mail notification (an smpt error came up, but that is not the issue here)

suddenly there was another option: **Publish Robot framework test results**

[image]

and that fixed it:

[image]

concluding: can Java open source work with the plugin?: apparently yes. (good to know)
What caused the option 'Publish Robot Framework test results  not showing? unclear!
Somehow triggering the E-mail Notification (remember? : which became available after the Matrix multi project plugin) solved the problem and the left pane options also showed in the menu at that point.

Comment: Did you install Matrix project then? Did you review the startup logs to see if a message why it was not loaded?

Comment: It would appear [JENKINS-36954](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-36954) is the culprit. I added steps to reproduce on the ticket, proposed sol'n,  which has been accepted and PR has been merged.  Expect to see it resolved in v.2.1.3. Consider marking response as accepted.